# Problema con scrabble

Tags: java

Soy nuevo tanto en programación como en esta pagina, estoy diseñando un `scrabble` con mis conocimientos básicos y escasos, el rollo es que no se como comprobar si la palabra que me han escrito por teclado contiene las letras que proporciona el programa mediante un `random` asignado al indice de un `array` con el alfabeto. por ahora tengo esto :D saludos!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scrabble {

static String palabra;
static char[] letras = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q',
        'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', };
static char[] opciones = new char[7];
static int puntos = 0;
static int puntoLetra;
static int puntoL[] = new int [7];
public static void Random() {

    System.out.println("Tus letras son: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        puntoLetra = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        int rand = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 26);
        System.out.println(letras[rand] + " = " + puntoLetra + " puntos.");
        opciones[i] = letras[rand];
        puntoL[i] = puntoLetra;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void Pedir() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Si has conseguido formar una palabra, introducela, de lo contrario teclea \"siguiente\" para pasar de ronda.");
    palabra = sc.nextLine();
    if(palabra.contains("siguiente")) {
        System.out.println("No has conseguido formar una palabra y no has ganado ningun punto \nTu puntuación actual es de " + puntos + " puntos.\n\nSiguiente ronda.\n");
        Random();
        Pedir();

    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {

        }
    }
}





public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random();
    Pedir();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Habría varias formar de validar que las letras de la entrada estén contenidas en el `array` con letras al azar seleccionas anteriormente. Como construye el `Array` de tipo `char[]` podría iterar sobre la palabra y obtener carácter por carácter por medio de `charAt` e ir comparando

```
if(palabra.contains("siguiente")) {
    System.out.println("No has conseguido formar una palabra y no has ganado"
               + " ningun punto \nTu puntuación actual es de " + puntos + ""
               + " puntos.\n\nSiguiente ronda.\n");
    Random();
    Pedir();

}else{
    boolean correcto = true;
    String options = new String(opciones);
    for(int i = 0; i < palabra.length() && correcto; i++) {
        if(!options.contains(String.valueOf(palabra.charAt(i)))){
            correcto=false; 
        }
    }
    if(correcto){
        System.out.println("Perfecto , ha completo la palabra");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Su Palaba contiene letras que no fueron seleccionadas");
    }
}
```